# jquery to change bootstrap radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been struggling for hours to set a bootstrap radio button using jquery.

Can any one help show me what I am doing wrong, below is a fiddle showing my code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeu/qu2jmxsd/)

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="xx" value="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="xx" value="is">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="xx" value="not">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </label>
</div>


jQuery(function($) {
  $('input:radio[name="xx"][value="is"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input:radio[name="xx"][value="is"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is changing the value of the input you want to 'checked' but the bootstrap visuals are not actually displaying this input. To get these visuals to match the actual value of your input an `active` state must be added to the `<label>` as well.

One way to achieve this is by using a click event instead.

`$('input').click();`

Another is by using:

`$('#your-button').button('toggle');`

This will toggle the button's active state, as suggested in the bootstrap documentation. You can read more about this and how buttons in bootstrap work [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/).